# Non-compactness of a set

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ be the set of all "infinite-tuples" $x=(x_1,x_2,...)$ of real numbers that end in an infinite string of $0$'s. Define an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ by the rule $<x,y>=\sum x_iy_i$. Let $\lVert x-y \rVert$ be the corresponding metric on $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$. Define:$$e_i=(0,...,0,1,0,...,0,...)$$ where $1$ appears in the $i^{th}$ place. Then the $e_i$ form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$. Let $X$ be the set of all the points $e_i$. Show that $X$ is closed, bounded, and non-compact.

I agree about the fact that $X$ is bounded and closed. But how to show that $X$ is non-compact? Can you give a proof without using convergent sequences, just using the definition of compactness?

Comment: Around each $e_i$ consider the open set consisting of points of distance at most $1/2$.  This doesn't contain any other $e_j$.

Answer (score 2):

Take a small enough neighbourhood $U_i$ for each $e_i$ (computing $\|e_i-e_j\|$ for $i\neq j$ will help). This makes an infinite cover and no open set can be removed.

Comment: Suppose I have only two $e_i$, that is $e_1=(1,0)$ and $e_2=(0,1)$. If I took two small neighbourhoods $U_1=B(e_1;\sqrt{2}/2)$ and $U_2=B(e_2;\sqrt{2}/2)$ they would cover X but I can't remove any open set; however X is compact! Where Am I wrong?

Comment: But this is not an infinite cover! Then, it has a suitable finite subcover, namely itself.